# jquery ui autocomplete displays only first item in db

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, spring-mvc, autocomplete

Am using JQuery Autocomplete on my templete, but as i get the results the Autocomplete only displays one item despite that the results that are fetched have more that one item. It only shows the first item on the list!

Example:

if i have a result list with `('type1', 'type2', 'type3')`

and on the autocomplete i type 't' it only displays `type1` on the drop down!

I am a newbie in jquery kindly rectify my mistakes( if any)

My autocomplete code:

```
$(".fro").each(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete({
                source : function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                    serviceUrl: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index.htm',
                    datatype: "json",
                    paramName: "fro",
                    delimiter: ",",
                    data : {
                        term : request.term
                    },      
                    success : function(data) {
                        response($.map(data.result, function(item) {
                            $.each(data, function() {
                                return {

                                       label : this.fro,
                                       value : this.fro
                               }
                            });
                        }));
                    }     
                });
            },
                minLength:1
            });
        });
```

[image]

My response controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTags.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=*/*")
      public @ResponseBody List<SearchFiller> getTags(@RequestParam("fro") String fro) {
          return simulateSearchResult(fro);
      }

      private List<SearchFiller> simulateSearchResult(String fro) {

        List<SearchFiller> data=searchFlightDao.fillerList();

        List<SearchFiller> result = new ArrayList<SearchFiller>();
            for (SearchFiller tag : data) {
                if (tag.getFro().contains(fro)) {
                    result.add(tag);
                }
            }

        return result;
      }
```

Right answer gets appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Let you try this:

```
$(".fro").each(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source : function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                serviceUrl: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index.htm',
                datatype: "json",
                paramName: "fro",
                delimiter: ",",
                data : {
                    term : request.term
                },      
                success : function(data) {
                    dataArray = new Array();
                    $.each(data, function() {
                        var t = { label : this.fro,  value : this.fro };
                        dataArray.push(t);
                    });
                    response(dataArray);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength:1
    });
});
```

Comment: when each function is placed as what u have said, I am getting error "misplaced constructs"  i had inserted each... see my edit. as of now the first data itself not displayed

Comment: plz help me out of this

Comment: sorry dude..ur edit not working..hope i should not restart my server .. for these edits..shall i come back

Comment: $("data.result").each(data.result, function() {  this is also not working

Comment: there's no error. in firebug itz showing http://localhost:8080/xxx/index.htm?term=ty whether term is right

Comment: dude..consider after inserting each ...first element too not working..any changes with in each syntax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79408/discussion-between-rajnikant-patel-and-ms-ibrahim).

Comment: can u try.. i had inserted image

Comment: can you do alert the dataArray? before sending reponse?